# TCP Slow Start Term Confusion

Tags: networking, tcp

I was confused with the term slow start. Why is TCP congestion control strategy called slow start when its size increases exponentially. If its called slow start because of small initial size, then shouldn't it be called low start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early (very early) implementations didn't use a congestion window. So they started very hard by sending a full receiver-window of data. Thus, aggressive as it may seem, slow-start is actually more conservative.